# Adapter or Proxy?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In a case where there are 3 classes and i need to choose 1 of the class to use. Then by using a standard method, i can access the file. The reason of having 1 standard method is to prevent re-writing of codes if different protocol is used.

Example, I have 3 classes called `MAPI`, `WebDAV`, `EWS`. Each class has their own method of retrieving information from Exchange Server. I want to have a class that have all the standard method to access each class. As a system admin, 1st i select which protocol to use, then i select what process the system should do (Retrieve information, update information etc). This way, the system admin does not need to have programming knowledge because he/she does not have to edit the code each time he/she change protocol.

Which design pattern should i use? Should i use the Adapter design pattern or Proxy design pattern? I am currently using Proxy design to design where there is a abstract class and another 3 of the classes, A B and C, and 1 additional class, Manager class, inherit the methods in abstract class.

I use Manager class to manage access to either 1 class. But then when i look at Adapter pattern, it seems like a better choice. Which should i use?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like neither adapter nor proxy design patterns are required here.

From your question, it sounds like you have a an abstract base class that provides a common interface for operations, and three concrete classes that use the different protocols, and a manager (factory) to instantiate the required concrete class. That sounds fine for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you **have not implemented** the support for MAPI, WebDAV, EWS as separate classes (libraries) **without common interface** then just do it using the **common interface**: there should be concrete implementations `(Providers`) of the common interface (`IDataProvider`), no design patterns needed.

If you **have already implemented** the support for MAPI, WebDAV, EWS as separate classes (libraries) **without common interface** then [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) will be good. For example, the concrete implementations does not have the common interface (see `Create()`, `CreateItem()`, `AddItem()` methods):

[image: Class diagram]

The Provider classes are the Adapters in this case.